# Can't download dSYM file from iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, dsym

I need to download the dSYM file so, as I usually do, I went to iTunes connect -> My app -> Activity -> All builds -> latest version.

"Include symbols" is Yes, but there is no link to download the dSYM file.

The app was uploaded 3 weeks ago, so also it's not like it's processing. Am I missing something stupid? Any idea?

[image]

Comment: I see 'Includes Symbols = Yes' but *NO* download link with 'Enable Bitcode = Yes' ?

Comment: do you have bitcode disabled?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Do you still have the archive available in Xcode as you can save them out from there:

1. Select Window -> Organizer
2. This will open up Organizer window containing your archives.
3. Right click on Archive and select 'Show in Finder'.
4. Right click archive in finder and select 'Show Package Contents'.
5. `Project.xcarchive` contains `dSYMs`, `Info.plist` and `Products`.
6. `dSYMs` folder contains dSYM file of your project.

You can enable the Debug Symbol file generation during build within Xcode as below.

[image]

Comment: that's actually right. I forgot that this app has bitcode disabled. I guess you have that link only if you enable bitcode.

Comment: What if I have no archives on my computer?

Comment: Did you guys have bitcode enabled when you uploaded from iTunes as you can download from there if you did

Comment: This should help on the Download From iTunes Connect bit: : https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/mobile-monitoring/new-relic-mobile-ios/install-configure/retrieve-upload-dsyms Log in to Apple iTunes Connect . Select My Apps > (select app) > Activity. From the list of builds for your application, select the build number you need. Select Download dSYM.

Comment: Do you need the dsym from exactly this archive that you built with xcode? Put another way: would the dsym file fit if you just re-build the same commit?

Comment: @Luca Torella，You said that the download link is related to the bitcode enable. Is this right? I just want to know why I can't get the download link.

Comment: I also cannot find a download link. I fear this may be a feature that was removed from iTunes Connect.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: It is weird that Apple asks for (a) enable or disable bitcode and in a different part (b) upload symbols.   This makes me infer that the upload of the dSym is independent of the bitcode setting, and Apple may or may not generate a new dSym if the app is not recompiled (i.e. no bitcode), but at least we could download the dSym we instructed the process to upload....

Comment: I have builds uploaded to App Store Connect with both enabled and disabled Bitcode. But there are no 'Download dSYM' link for all of these builds.

Answer (score 24):

I got the same issue today. But I've been using Fastlane and do not have any archives inside the project organizer. So the only option is to get it from Appstore. I think it's a bug from the Appstore side. Just don't click the "Download dSYM" button. Just copy the link and open it on a new tab. Then you could download the dSYM's

[image]

Comment: Apple / XCode is great but some trivial things like this make you lose hours if not a day or two ... I was wondering why the click was not downloading anything .. what made you think to try this out !?

Comment: @ShawnFrank I was trying to debug and access the link. When I try to copy and paste the link on the new tab it worked fine :D

Comment: This worked for me (Clicking directly didn't work on Brave 1.32.113). Thanks

Answer (score 10):

It seems 'Download dSYM file' link is intended for downloading dSYMs generated by App Store when bitcode is enabled. Thus if bitcode is disabled for your application dSYM files are contained by your Mac. If bitcode enabled the final compilation of your binary will be execute on App Store and new dSYM will be generated. And new dSYM you will be able to download from App Store Connect with 'Download dSYM file'.

See 'Bitcode' section in [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008184-CH1-SYMBOLICATION-BITCODE).

Comment: When bitcode disable, appstore connect link button will not show.

Answer (score 7):

I had a similar issue and the accepted answer didn't work for me. AppCenter was asking for some missing symbols, and it didn't accept the ones from the app's archive (it needed the dSym's with random letters and numbers in the file name)

In AppstoreConnect, All Builds -> Current Version -> Current Build -> Includes Symbols said YES, but no download link. BitCode was enabled when I published the app.

I just waited a couple more days (I think that there were 5 days in total) and the Download dSYM link appeared.

Comment: From my experience dSYMs can appear with a slight delay but I didn’t have to wait more than 1-2 hours usually. If they don’t appear in that time it usually means that we don’t have bitcode included or some other problem in the building process.

Answer (score 5):

Recently encountered an issue with download link being broken when clicking download dSYM from AppStore Connect. Turned out that the link generated was just missing an "s" in http:// so the browser was blocking it.
Happens only for certain browsers. If this happens to you, try adding an "s" to have the link start with https://....

Comment: You save my day, thanks a lot.

Comment: Yep, still happening to me on chrome, glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

App Store DSYM is different for our local DSYM,When bitcode disable you can user local DSYM,when bitcode enable,you should user App Store DSYM.

Answer (score 0):

Just to bring this up to date as of Xcode 12.2, Apple is allowing Xcode to download the symbols.

1. Go to the Organizer and find the app you uploaded to the store.
2. Click the Download Debug Symbols button beneath Details.
3. Right-click the app and Show In Finder.
4. Right-click the xcarchive and Show Package Contents
5. Your dSYMs are in the folder...

[image]

Comment: Just clarifying this: the steps you provide are not about downloading dSYMs from the App Store Connect version of your app, they are about retrieving them from the archive you built locally and then published.
For people and teams not building archives locally (e.g. using a CI provider) this won't work as XCode's Archives screen will be empty or at least won't show the app as it doesn't exist locally on your machine.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

An update for Xcode 14. I've had missing dSym links for my last few releases and asked Apple support for help. They responded with:

> The generation of the “download dSYM” link is dependent on whether an app upload includes bitcode.
>
> With the release of Xcode 14 and up, the use of bitcode is deprecated, and the App Store no longer accepts bitcode submissions from Xcode 14.
>
> Further information can be found on the following website:
>
> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes

I now use the accepted answer and locate the dSym files from the Organiser > Show in Finder method