# There is no Download dSYM option on iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, dsym

I need to download dSYM file from iTunes Connect.

I can see "Include symbols" is Yes, but there is no link to download the dSYM file.

Any idea why the option is not there?

Comment: If the app was submitted with symbols in the first place, you should see the option "Download dSYM" if not check `Build Settings -> Debug Information -> Format -> Release -> DWARF with dSYM File` in xcode

Comment: I'm using Xcode 7.3.1 and have this all setup, including DWARF with dSYM option, yet when submitting to testflight I can see "Includes Symbols: Yes" with no option to download dSYM.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397972/cant-download-dsym-file-from-itunes-connect

Comment: Did u find the solution @neha, i am also facing same issue .

Answer (score 4):

with Xcode 8,9,10,11 and above

```
 * Select Window -> Organizer
 * will open up Organizer window
 * Right click on Specific Archive and select 'Show in Finder' option
 * Right click archive in finder and select 'Show Package Contents'.
 * Project.xcarchive contains dSYMs, Info.plist and Products.
 * dSYMs folder contains dSYM file of your project.
```

Comment: This only works if you uploaded the project from your computer using Xcode.

Comment: Like @LluisGerard mentioned, this isn't helpful if you're generating builds and uploading them via CI/CD. Can confirm that the link disappeared for us as well.

Answer (score 1):

you may need to go in

> activity -> select build which build dSYM file is need here is display download dSYM

click and download specific build dSYM file.