# Missing dSYM after uploading to App Center

Tags: ios, fastlane, hockeyapp, visual-studio-app-center

I am using latest fastlane (2.114) and appcenter plugin. During the build I see this in the log:

```
Binary uploaded
..
dSYM uploaded
```

I do not know how to verify if dSYM is actually uploaded to App Center, but in the Hockeyapp I do see the build, but do not see dSYM. Instead I see Symbols none.

[image]
Why? How can I fix this?

I use plugin like this:

```
appcenter_upload(
    api_token: "my_token",
    owner_name: "my_company",
    group: "Collaborators,some-other-group",
    app_name: "app-name",
    ipa: "ipa-path",
    dsym: "dsym-path"
)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't download dSYM file from iTunes connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36397972/cant-download-dsym-file-from-itunes-connect)

Answer (score 0):

Your screenshot, is from hockeyapp (https://rink.hockeyapp.net) and not from appcenter (https://appcenter.ms), that is why your dSym stuff is missing.

You can also use the appcenter-cli (e.g. from npm).

1. Create new Release: appcenter distribute release ...
2. Upload symbols: appcenter crashes upload-symbols ...

Comment: You can also use the API from AppCenter to upload symbols. https://openapi.appcenter.ms/#/crash/symbolUploads_create